# Laravel change profile api gives null value

Tags: laravel-5.7

I am making change profile picture api in laravel .I want to update profile image in users table but not inserting or updating my images .Belew are my code please help me how to update user table .

**fileUploadController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use App\Detail;
use App\Profile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Session;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class FileUploadController extends Controller
{

     public function changeProfile(Request $request,$id){

        $this->validate($request, [

            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',

        ]);

         $updateuser = User::find($id);


         if($file = $request->hasFile('image')) {

            $file = $request->file('image');

            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/files/' ;
            $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);
            $updateuser->image = '/files/'.$fileName;
        }

        $updateuser->save();
        return $updateuser;

     }

}
```

Comment: `if($file = $request->hasFile('image')) {` ????????? why not just `if($request->hasFile('image'))`

Comment: Can you please `dd($request->all())` right before `$this->validate` and show us the output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function changeProfile(Request $request,$id){

    $this->validate($request, [

        'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',

    ]);

     $updateuser = User::find($id);
    if($request->hasFile('image'))
    {
        $filewithext = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
        $ext = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileToStrore = $filewithext;
        $path = $request->file('image')->storeAs('public/files',$fileToStrore);
        $updateuser->image = $fileToStrore;
    }


    $updateuser->save();
    return $updateuser;

 }
```

This code works for me. I hope it will work for you too...
Good Luck..

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me.....

**fileUploadController.php** 
     public function changeProfile(Request $request,$id){

```
         $updateuser = User::find($id);

        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
               $images = $request->file('image');
               $destinationPath = public_path('files');
               $imageName = time().'.'.$images->getClientOriginalExtension();
               $images->move($destinationPath, $imageName); 
               $updateuser->image= $imageName;
            }else{
              $updateuser->image= '';
            }

      $updateuser->update();

       return ['message' => 'Image Uploaded Successfully'];
     }
```